# How could i better this process? I feel like i went too far

Tags: java, switch-statement, try-catch, java.util.scanner, do-while

"Is there a better way of doing this? I feel like I'm over doing this. Ideally I'm just asking the user a question, having them input their answer, handling exceptions, confirming their original answer, and then handling those potential exceptions. I basically just want to ask a question and handle any issue and then confirm that selection.

** I know i don't have certain objects visible. This is more of a general code layout question rather than "Why doesn't my code work, because this does work it just feel like i typed a lot for a little.**

```
int y = 0;
    do {
        int x = 0;
        do {

            try {

                System.out.println("Please select which class you would like to be!");

                System.out.println("1. Magician");
                System.out.println("2. Archer");
                System.out.println("3. Warrior");

                int classSelection = sc.nextInt();

                switch (classSelection) {

                case 1:
                    Hero.magicianClass();
                    System.out.println("You have selected the Magician class\n");
                    x = 1;
                    break;

                case 2:
                    Hero.archerClass();
                    System.out.println("You have selected the Archer class\n");
                    x = 1;
                    break;

                case 3:
                    Hero.warriorClass();
                    System.out.println("You have selected the Warrior class\n");
                    x = 1;
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("You have incorrectly selected your class. Please try again!\n");
                    x = 0;
                    break;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("You did no insert an integer. Please try again!\n");
                sc.next();
            }
        } while (x == 0);

        try {
            Hero.displayClass();
            System.out.println("Are you certain that you want to be a " + Hero.checkClassName + "?");
            System.out.println("\npress 0 for no\npress 1 for yes");
            int selection = sc.nextInt();
            switch (selection) {
            case 1:
                y = 0;
                x = 0;
            case 2:
                y = 1;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("You did not insert an integer. Please try again!\n");
            sc.next();
        }

    } while (y == 0);
```

Comment: Basically, you are asking for someone to review your code.  That's not appropriate on StackOverflow.  But there is a another site - https://codereview.stackexchange.com - where questions like this are welcome.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the codereview site.

Comment: My apologies i wasn't aware there were different code forums. Ill go there